# Alpha numeric sequence generation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate the custom sequence as below using javascript based on input. For ex: if i provide the input is`AA1` then output should be `AA2` and if  provided input as `AA9` then the output should be `AB0`. I can do with the if else by creating the token's but it looks like we need to keep so many if else condition's. Wanted to know the more efficient way to handle this.

```
AA0
AA1
AA2
AA3
AA4
AA5
AA6
AA7
AA8
AA9
AB0
AB1
AB2
AB3
AB4
AB5
AB6
AB7
AB8
AB9
AC0
AC1
.
.
.
ZZ9
```

Comment: so it's adding 1 in hex? - edit: no

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's actually alphabet characters in first two followed by incrementing of numeric from 0 till 9 for every sequence like AA0, AA1...AA9, AB0, AB1...AB9,ZA0,ZA1...ZZ9

Comment: Use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) and try something.

Comment: what is the next value of `'AZ9'`?

Comment: I would assume it is `'BA0'`

Comment: @NinaScholz it would be BA0, BA1,BA2...BA9,BB0,BB1...BB9,BC0,BC1...BC9

Comment: Can you show us your code with the "many if else conditions" that you're thinking of, please? (You can abbreviate it where you think it's repetitive). But yes, you will need some conditions to handle the [carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)). Otherwise it's just simple arithmetic addition in an uncommon (and mixed!) base.

Comment: Will it always take the form of `[letter][letter][digit]` or doesn't it need to handle more dynamic strings like "B8A" or "AAB7"?

Comment: @JustinTaddei it's always like [letter][letter][digit] with the mentioned sequence. This was actually a business requirement

Answer (score 1):

Using [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) you can iterate over the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) string in reverse, incrementing each character as necessary using the character's [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) value adjusted by its offset from 0, and cycling it based on its [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) for the appropriate cycle length (10 for integers, 26 for letters). The accumulator tracks whether to sum on the next iteration, as well as the result string.

```js
const incrementAlphaNumeric = (str) => {
  let iter, min, len;
  return [...str]
    .reduceRight((a, c, i) => {
      let code = c.charCodeAt();
      if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) { // [0-9]
        min = 48;
        len = 10;
      } else if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90)) { // [A-Z]
        min = 65;
        len = 26;
      }
      iter = code - min + a.sum;
      a.res[i] = String.fromCharCode(iter % len + min);
      a.sum = Math.floor(iter / len);
      return a;
    }, { res: [], sum: 1 })
    .res
    .join('');
}

console.log(incrementAlphaNumeric('AA0')); // AA1
console.log(incrementAlphaNumeric('AA9')); // AB0
console.log(incrementAlphaNumeric('AZ9')); // BA0
console.log(incrementAlphaNumeric('ZZ9')); // AA0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take two function for gettign a deciaml or the fancy value and check if the last digit is nine.

```js
function increment(value) {
    const
        decimal = s => Array
            .from(s, v => parseInt(v, 36) - 10)
            .reduce((s, v) => s * 26 + v, 0),
        fancy = n => Array
            .from(n.toString(26), v => (parseInt(v, 26) + 10).toString(36))
            .join('')
            .toUpperCase(),
        [left, right] = value.match(/\D+|\d+/g);

    if (value === 'ZZ9') return 'AA0';

    return right === '9'
        ? fancy(decimal(left) + 1) + '0'
        : left + (+right + 1);
}

console.log(increment('AA0')); // AA1
console.log(increment('AZ9')); // BA0
console.log(increment('ZZ9')); // AA0
```

Comment: `increment('ZZ9')` results in `'BAA0'`

Comment: and what is the wanted value instead?

Comment: The OP said in a comment that "...it's always like [letter][letter][digit] with the mentioned sequence. This was actually a business requirement" so I would assume `AA0` would be excpected.

Comment: I think you meant `value` instead of `v`: `Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I had a little time on my hands, and this seemed like a fun challenge, so I went ahead and built a function that accepts any string of uppercase letters and/or numbers. I realize it might be a little bit overkill for the requirements of the question, but it does satisfy all of the requirements, and someone else stumbling across this question in the future might find this helpful.

It works by converting the right-most character to its respective character code, incrementing it by `1`, and checking if the resulting character code is outside of the `A-Z` or `0-9` range. If it is outside of its range, we reset it to its "base value" (`A` or `0`) and set a `carry` flag (this is very similar to how binary adder circuits work). If the `carry` flag is set, we recursively call the function using the next-to-last character as our new "right-most" character until we no longer need to carry. At which point, we simply return the new string.

`increment('AA0') > 'AA1`
`increment('AA9') > 'AB0`
`increment('ZZ9') > 'AA0`

`increment('AZ9BE') > 'AZ9BF`

```js
const A = 65
const Z = 90
const ZERO = 48
const NINE = 57

const isDigit = (char) => char >= 48 && char <= 57

const incDigit = (char) => char + 1 > NINE ? ZERO : char + 1
const incLetter = (char) => char + 1 > Z ? A : char + 1

const codeToChar = (code) => String.fromCharCode(code)
const setChar = (index, char, str) => {
    const charArr = [...str]
    charArr.splice(index, 1, char)
    return charArr.join('')
}


const increment = (str, place = str.length - 1) => {
    if (place < 0) return str;

    const char = str.charCodeAt(place)

    const nextChar = isDigit(char) ? incDigit(char) : incLetter(char)

    const carry = nextChar - char !== 1;

    str = setChar(place, codeToChar(nextChar), str)

    if (carry)
        return increment(str, --place)
    else return str
}


let demoStr = 'AA0'
setInterval(() => {
    demoStr = increment(demoStr)
    console.log(demoStr)
}, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `next()` function, which increments the letters of the input string by converting them to base 26 numeric strings and back whenever an overflow is detected from incrementing the decimal portion of the input string:

```js
const next = (() => {
  const charCodeA = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  const to = (replacer, string) => string.replace(/./g, replacer);
  const padStart = (string, { length }, pad) => string.padStart(length, pad);
  const truncate = (string, { length }) => string.slice(-length);
  const letter = (base26String) => String.fromCharCode(
    parseInt(base26String, 26) + charCodeA
  );
  const base26 = (letterString) => (
    letterString.charCodeAt(0) - charCodeA
  ).toString(26);
  const increment = (numbersString, radix) => (
    parseInt(numbersString, radix) + 1
  ).toString(radix);

  return (prev) => {
    const [, prevL, prevD] = prev.match(/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/);
    const nextD = padStart(increment(prevD, 10), prevD, '0');
    const carry = nextD.length > prevD.length;
    const nextL = carry
      ? padStart(to(letter, increment(to(base26, prevL), 26)), prevL, 'A')
      : prevL;
    return truncate(nextL, prevL) + truncate(nextD, prevD);
  };
})();

console.log(next('AA0')); // AA1
console.log(next('AZ9')); // BA0
console.log(next('ZZ9')); // AA0
console.log(next('AAA00')); // AAA01
console.log(next('AZZ09')); // AZZ10
console.log(next('AZZ99')); // BAA00
console.log(next('ZZZ99')); // AAA00
```

#### References

- [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)
- [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)